# Example of a graph property which is not monotone

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

A graph property $Q$ is called *monotone increasing* if $\forall$ graph $G \in Q$, we have $G + e \in Q$, where $e \in K_n $\ $ G$ ,  ($K_n $ being Complete graph). So basically it is preserved by the addition of edges.

Example - Connectivity.

Likewise the term *monotone decreasing* can be defined as follow - A graph property $Q'$ is called *monotone decreasing* if if $\forall$ graph $G \in Q$, we have $G - e \in Q$.

Example - Graphs with at least one isolated vertex.

But I am not able to figure out any graph property which is neither increasing nor decreasing. Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about regularity? Being 3-regular (where every vertex has 3 edges) is neither monotone increasing or monotone decreasing. Other examples might include being bipartite, or being a tree (with the understanding that a tree is a connected acyclic graph), or other shape-dependent properties.

Comment: Being bipartite is in fact monotone decreasing: if you remove edges from a bipartite graph, it remains bipartite.